# Django query with multiple foreign keys does not seem to work

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I am trying to get a record from the table Answer that corresponds to the foreign keys Learner and Problem. The Problem foreign key though is not given; Outcome is available instead. I cannot seem to make my query work. Can anybody point to me what I am doing wrong?

```
#Model classes:
class Answer(models.Model):
    problem = models.ForeignKey('Problem', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False, help_text="Problem ID")
    learner = models.ForeignKey('Learner', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False, help_text="Learner ID")
    try_count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0,
        help_text="Number of times the problem was attempted")
    correct = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False, default='0',
        choices=Constant.CORRECT,
        help_text="Indicator whether the problem was answered correctly or not")
    ...

class Problem(models.Model):
    outcome = models.ForeignKey('Outcome', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False, help_text="Outcome ID")
    ...

class Outcome(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, unique=True,
        help_text="Outcome name")
    ...

class Learner(models.Model):
    anonymous_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False,
        help_text="Anonymous ID")
    ...

# Query
answer = Answer.objects.filter(learner=learner,
    problem__outcome=outcome).order_by('correct', 'try_count')[0]
```

Thank you!

Comment: looks like you can change correct to `BooleanField` instead on `CharField` and storing it as 1 or 0

Comment: Your query should work unless the Answer has not entry of `Problem`.

Comment: Do you get any results when you run simpler versions of your query?
`Answer.objects.filter(learner=learner)` and `Answer.objects.filter(problem__outcome=outcome`?

Comment: @malberts, yes, I do get results using the simpler query versions above.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I guess you are referring to the Correct field? It expects other values aside from just yes/no (partially, unknown).

Comment: @MayKristine When you run those 2 simple queries, can you confirm that the item you are looking for actually exists in both sets of results?

Comment: @malberts Yes, I can confirm that the item I am looking for exists. I have created entries where both queries should return the same result, and it can be retrieved correctly. I am starting to suspect my problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @malberts Already found that my problem was due to something else. My recent code changes just managed to uncover it. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the outcome as ID and not the outcome as object. If that is the case then try changing the query to the following:

```
answer = Answer.objects.filter(learner=learner,
problem__outcome__id=outcome).order_by('correct', 'try_count')[0]
```

If you are having the learner as ID and outcome as ID, try the following:

```
answer = Answer.objects.filter(learner__id=learner,
problem__outcome__id=outcome).order_by('correct', 'try_count')[0]
```

Please note that I have added __id after learner and outcome.

Comment: Outcome is an object. I tried though to pass the Outcome ID instead, still not good. :(

Comment: Same thing for learner. I already found my problem, and it is not on this code part. I guess I should just accept this answer for closure. Thanks for your help!